# SelfDeleting application in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to delete a folder which contains the currently running application. How can i do it..? is there any way of doing it ? i.e the folder which contains the application should delete after the application has finished running ?

Comment: Someone is writing a troyan ;)

Comment: What OS? Getting the folder that contains the current process' executable is a bit of a pain

Comment: @Michael: Probably Windows as it's VC++

Comment: Ah yes, my brain ignored the V

Comment: @java.is.for.desktop: Not necessarily.

Comment: @java.is.for.desktop - surprisingly enough, there are some valid reasons you'd want to create a self-deleting executable. Not many, granted, but a few!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use the Win32 API [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(v=VS.85).aspx).  It has a flag that can be set for deleting files when they are in use on the next reboot called `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`.  Set the new filename parameter of `MoveFileEx` to `NULL` to perform this type of delete.

> If dwFlags specifies
>   MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and
>   lpNewFileName is NULL, MoveFileEx
>   registers the lpExistingFileName file
>   to be deleted when the system
>   restarts.

Note: Normal files that are in use can be deleted normally using the Win32 API [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915(VS.85).aspx) depending on if they were opened (Using the Win32 API `CreateFile`) with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` permission.  I don't think running programs by default on Windows have that permission though.  When a file is specified to be deleted that is in use but that was opened with this flag, then the file will be removed when the last file handle is closed.

Comment: The directory is not empty it contains files in it.

Comment: @rajivpradeep: That is fine, you can use DeleteFile for the files that can be deleted in the folder, and MoveFileEx for the files that cannot.

Comment: I am trying some thing. i'll getback

Answer (score 1):

This is hairy. I had to implement this once for a self-patching app, where the patcher had to (by client request) delete itself after installing the patch. You can do this by launching a helper DLL which deletes your process, along with itself.

The full method for deleting your process can be found here: http://www.handcraftedbytes.com/articles/writing-install-and-uninstall

As others have pointed out, you're not going to be able to delete the folder that your executable resides in while it exists there. My suggestion is to:

- Use [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to move your executable off to a temporary directory,
- delete your application's directory,
- delete your executable using the self-deleting DLL method described in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an executable file that is currently running, however you *can* delete a batch file that is currently running (cmd.exe loads the whole file into memory and then you can delete it).

So the simplest solution would be to launch a batch that tries to delete the .exe in a loop (because it may not work the first time - until your .exe has been unloaded) and then exit your process - with the batch file still running.